# specify which series groups should be plotted on which Y Axes

Tags: jqplot

I am trying to figure out if its possible to series group plotting 
with respect to Y axes 
for example i have 5 series

physics, chemistry, maths , literature, programming .

assume my data is also in the above order 
when i plot the graph normally without giving different y axes it will 
generate the graphs corresponding to default  y axis,

if specify{ yaxis : 'y2axis'} it will print the chemistry graph on 
secondary y axes while all other graphs are print w.r.t  y axis. 
and i can plot all these five elements on different y axes by specifying the corresponding {yaxis:yNaxis}

is there any way by which i can specify that plot 
physics, chemistry on y1 axis and rest three subjects on y2 axis? 
currently by default it plots the graph w.r.t y axis and if we specify 
yaxis : 'y2axis' only a single graph would be plotted for y2 .

Answer (score 2):

You can specify which axis a series is plotted to by specifying the `yaxis` value in the `series` info for that series, like so:

```
series: [
  {
    label: 'Physics',
    yaxis: 'y2axis',
    ... other data here ...
  },
  {
    label: 'Chemistry',
    yaxis: 'yaxis',
    ... other data here ...
  },
  ... etc ...
]
```

Hope that helps!